# Accessing data from the jcr from jsp

Tags: aem, jcr

In some implementations, I've seen jsp's using java bean classes acting as an intermediate store/data access layer to get data from a jcr.

Why is this, since the jsp can access the jcr directly via the jcr api.

Separation of concerns? Memory cache for the data?

Just wondering why such a pattern exists when the jcr api was written in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using scriptlet's might not be so problematic in smaller installations but is in large multi site projects.

Separating UI code and model/business logic eases maintainability and allows reusability of code upon projects. Also changing layout's gets much easier. Usually this seperation is done by using a component bean to access the JCR repo and to provide the data and by using the JSP just for the view.

Just imagine that your customer requires a large UI change propably in multiple sites. It's harder to change JSPs mixed up with scriptlets and UI code, especially if you have a lot of them.

From an OO perspective using JSPs and scriptlets prevents you from using inheritance and composition. Scriptlet's can not be made abstract.
I experienced that java beans are easier to debug then scriptlets, especially in case of an exception and java beans can be easier unit tested.